# Как убрать ошибку Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Есть код

```
$body = file_get_contents('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q='.urlencode($querys));
$json = json_decode($body);
foreach ($json->responseData->results as $result) {
   echo '<a href="' . $randurl . '">' . $result->title . '</a>';
   echo '' . $result->content . '';
}
```

хост на котором работает скрипт видимо забанен гуглем. Сама ошибка **Warning:** в строке **foreach($json->responseData->results as $result**. Подскажите пожалуйста, как допилить сам скрипт чтобы убрать код ошибки, т.е. если ответ 403, то ничего совсем не выдавать на страницу. Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [curl](https://www.php.net/curl), в частности посмотрите функцию [curl_errno](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-errno.php)

неправильный метод:
проверить что строка json? например так

```
function isJson($string) {
 json_decode($string);
 return (json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE);
}
```

если нет, то не продолжать

Comment: а почему-бы условие не вставить прям в код ? зачем сто раз делать decode одного и того-же...

Comment: Можно, но если оно в нескольких местах будет, то на мой взгляд функция лучше ЕСЛИ вдруг чтото править надо будет. Ну вообщем на вкус и цвет... :) Но я бы curl использовал, вообще получать наддые из сети методом file_get_contents не самая хорошая и удобная идея.

Comment: какая разница в нескольких местах прописывать 

    if (json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE) {}

или 

      if (isJson) {}

?

можно улучшить, возвращая объект/false в вашей функции...

Comment: ну например, если я вдруг захочу сделать логгирование этой ошибки.... да,ессно,можно улучшить или ухудшить, это просто пример же

Answer (score 0):

```
$body = file_get_contents('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q='.urlencode($querys));
$json = json_decode($body);
if (isset($json->responseData->results)){
   foreach ($json->responseData->results as $result) {
      echo '<a href="' . $randurl . '">' . $result->title . '</a>';
      echo '' . $result->content . '';
   }
}
```

Comment: варнинги полезут ибо responseData уже не существует, неговоря о results :) а скорее всего вообще с fatal error вылетит ибо $json не объект.

Comment: Проверил, не полезли. для теста специально `$body` присвоил белиберду всякую и скрипт отработал без варнинга и без фаталеррора. Хотя может будет зависеть от настроек, тестировал на дефолтном OpenServer.

Comment: если варнинги-ошибки отключены, то ничего не вылезет, конечно

Comment: включены, ибо если убрать условие, они вылазят )))

Comment: @aldem67 ох, типичный PHP-way. Не "у меня точно E_ALL стоит", а "вылазят если условие убрать))))". Вот вам нотариальный скриншот, Yii бы на первом же нотисе сдохла (и правильно бы сделала, тогда хотя бы в логах осталась ошибка 500):
http://imgur.com/d3veMdS
Почему PHP на такое выдает всего лишь Notice - отдельная тема для полноценного срача за языки.

Comment: notice и warning разные уровни "ошибок" ))). Один проект сейчас на джумле, и с включеным Notice там жить нельзя, поэтому они да, отключены. )))

Comment: Спасибо Вам Большое. Теперь все получилось!
p.s. теперь попробую переписать все через курл, все же в 100 раз быстрее ответ отдается чем через филежетконткнт.